# SOAP WSS Header xsd format

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd

I am trying to create an XSD schema of the required WS-Security SOAP header so that it can be imported into Cast Iron and used to properly format the outgoing SOAP header. I've come up with the following so far, but apparently it isn't quite formatted properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
           xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <xs:Security mustUnderstand="1">
    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="">
      <wsu:Created/>
      <wsu:Expires/>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="">
      <wsse:Username/>
      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"/>
      <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"/>
      <wsu:Created/>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </xs:Security>
</xs:schema>
```

Can someone help me out with the proper format for the XSD? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found a valid version of the XSD [here](https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/LETSI_RTWS_Client/blob/master/xsds/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0-restricted.xsd).